# Correct way to detect when multiple threads finished - Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote the following method to run multiple threads in parallel and when all threads are complete I want to trigger some further action. I've attached a propertyChangeListener to each object that runs in its own thread and each of those objects fires a property changed event when its thread completes. So on each of those events I increment a count and compare it to the size of the list of objects. Once they are equal I know all threads are finished. However, this seems like a bit of a hash up and I'm quite new to multi-threading, so I thought I'd ask what others think of my approach and whether there are more elegant or robust approaches. Thanks.

```
private void jButtonRunSubsetsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        count = 0;
        List<SpeciesSelection> specSelList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String str : fileList) {
            // TODO RUN THE FILES
            if (!str.equals("")) {
                String[] args = {str};
                //run solution
                SpeciesSelection specSel = new SpeciesSelection(args, true);
                specSelList.add(specSel);// add the thread to the list so we can check for all threads to be finished.

                // Create listener to listen for specSel finished
                specSel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                        // TODO do something
                        count++;
                        if (count == specSelList.size())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Finished all threads");
                        }
                    }
                });

                Thread t = new Thread(specSel);
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just `Thread.join()`?

Comment: I want my GUI to remain responsive with the option to cancel all the threads if required. I think that's also an issue with using CountDownLatch.await() so maybe my solution is not bad after all

Comment: You don't have to block the UI, just spawn another thread where you will start the latch and the other threads.

Comment: I would combine the advice given by Tschallacka and NiVeR:  Fire off one additional thread.  It's job is to `join()` all of the workers, trigger the "further action," and then die.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using an `int` counter and check its value use `CountDownLatch` that is designed to.

```
CountDownLatch count = new CountDownLatch(nbRequiredCount);
count.await();
```

The `await()` doesn't return while the counter is not to `0`.

and decrement it in threads :

```
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
    // TODO do something
    count.countDown();
}
```

Comment: Fun stuff, I answered sooner, with a more complete answer and you get the upvote. The beauty of stackoverflow. This is not a protest, I am joking obviously :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class `CountDownLatch` like this:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(N);
```

where `N` is the number of threads you launch. You pass around this object and call the `latch.countDown()` each time a thread finishes. Once they are all done, the latch will release control to the parent thread.

Comment: This things that happen but note that your answer may be read as misleading. I think that the OP is not clear in the description of what he/she doesn't actually and you go into its way. You said : "You pass around this object and call the latch.countDown() each time a thread finishes". But look at the code : that is not what the OP does actually. The counter is not incremented at the end of the `run()`  method. Same thing for `CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(N);` where you say that `N` is the number of threads you launch. According to the actual code, I am not sure that it works.

Comment: When he upvoted your answer, it contained just that they should use the latch, therefore your argument is not valid.

Comment: Indeed. A concise answer that proposes the API to use is probably more helpful than providing a more detailed but probably misleading answer.

Comment: I don't agree,  I don't see it as misleading at all. But it is ok, the important thing the problem is solved.

Comment: Which further more confirms my point, that whoever voted the answer looked just at the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Using the advice given, I altered my code as follows:

```
private void jButtonRunSubsetsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        List<SpeciesSelection> specSelList = new ArrayList<>();
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int numberFiles = fileList.size();
                    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(numberFiles);
                    for (String str : fileList) {
                        // TODO RUN THE FILES
                        if (!str.equals("")) {
                            String[] args = {str};
                            //run solution
                            SpeciesSelection specSel = new SpeciesSelection(args, true);
                            specSelList.add(specSel);// add the thread to the list so we can check for all threads to be finished.

                            // Create listener to listen for specSel finished
                            specSel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                                    latch.countDown();
                                }
                            });
                            Thread t = new Thread(specSel);
                            t.start();
                        }
                    }
                    latch.await();
                    System.out.println("Finished all threads");
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(SpecSelGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

I used the CountDownLatch as suggested but also ran the multiple processes inside an additional anonymous thread so that I could call latch.await() without freezing up the main thread/GUI responsiveness.